# How to perform a class method of a class which is casted from NSClassFromString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, casting

I tried to use a class which is created from *NSClassFromString* to perform a class method, but I failed.

In Objective-C, it's easy:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:[NSClassFromString(reuseIdentifier) cellStyle] reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
         let sel = #selector(CTFeedbackTopicCellItem.cellStyle())
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

And in Swift it's not easy:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    if let reuseIdentifier2 = reuseIdentifier
    {
        if let class2 = NSClassFromString(reuseIdentifier2) as? NSObjectProtocol
        {
            let sel = #selector(CTFeedbackCellItem.cellStyle())

            if let class3 = class2 as? CTFeedbackCellItem
            {
                super.init(style: class3.cellStyle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error shown in my Swift code so far are:
 1. Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property or initializer.
 2. Stastic member 'cellType' cannnot be used on instance of type 'CTFeedbackCellItem'

Comment: It seems that your solution is overly complicated. Why do you do it like that? Can't you use protocols/inheritance to achieve the same thing?

Comment: I am converting a open source to Swift. The classes created from reuseIdentifier have different cellType, so it did like this way.

The simpler way I see here is only like this: 
````if let class2 = NSClassFromString(reuseIdentifier2) as? CTFeedbackCellItem```  
But compiler says "Cast from AnyObject to unrelated type ''CTFeedbackCellItem' alwyas fails".

Can you make it simpler in any way?

Comment: Since you are converting the open source, why not take the opportunity to fix their mistake and do it properly

Comment: If they all have this property `cellType` than it is a clear case for a protocol :) Anyway, this whole initializer looks weird. If you are already initializing this class, can't you just take its `cellType`? Can you link to the library you are converting?

Comment: There are 5 subclasses of CTFeedbackCellItem there, and they got cellType like UITableViewCellStyle.default or UITableViewCellStyle.value1.

It can be a protocol, yes.

The source code is here, https://github.com/rizumita/CTFeedback/tree/master/Classes

And the answer by @OOPer seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    guard let reuseIdentifier = reuseIdentifier else {
        fatalError("bad usage")
    }
    guard let itemClass = NSClassFromString(reuseIdentifier) as? CTFeedbackCellItem.Type else {
        fatalError("bad reuseIdentifier")
    }
    super.init(style: itemClass.cellStyle(), reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
```

(If you have implemented your `cellStyle` as a class property, change `itemClass.cellStyle()` to `itemClass.cellStyle`.)

Class object is not an instance of the class, so you should not cast it like an instance. Cast it to meta-class, if you want to call class methods. No need to use `#selector`.